# Investigating the relevance maxim

Tags: discourse-analysis

Is the speaker relevant to the conversation in these situations (as per the title, I'm investigating the relevant maxim in these situations):

- Situation 1:

  > BARBARA: I. I guess I'm just sort of not prepared to talk about your stuff.
  >   VIOLET: Suit yourself.
  >   STEVE: The food is just spectacular
- Situation 2:

  > VIOLET: I haven't tried much of it, yet.
  >   BARBARA: Johnna cooked this whole meal by herself.
  >   VIOLET: It’s what she's paid for. You all did know she's getting paid, right?
  >   CHARLIE: Jean, so I'm curious, when you say you don't eat meat, you mean you don’t eat meat of any kind?
- Situation 3:

  > BILL: Let’s eat.
  >   VIOLET: Barb, have any use for that sideboard?
  >   BARBARA: Hm
- Situation 4:

  > Jean: When you eat meat, you ingest an animal's fear.
  >   VIOLET: Ingest what? It's fur?
  >   JEAN: Fear.

Comment: It would be appropriate if you said what would be your answers in such cases, possibly giving the reason why. Other users might be more willing to help you in that case.

Comment: I think that they  steve in situation 1 ,violet in situation 2  and situation 3 and 4 are irrelevant but I'm not really sure . I'm confused

Comment: Each individual in your examples is a speaker, so *the* speaker is conceptually problematic. You also either need to tell us what maxim you consider to be relevant, or else refer to the Maxim of Relevance or even better the Maxim of Relation. It's a proper name.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because so far it looks like "do my homework".

Comment: I'm just asking for another opinion  because the situations seemed confusing that's it :)

Answer (score 2):

If you **do** mean to refer to Grice's Maxim of Relevance, and the examples suggest you do, then you must understand that, unlike other maxims, it's impossible to violate the Relevance Maxim.

This is because Relevance is under the control of the **addressee**, not the speaker.
No matter what the speaker may intend, the relevance of an utterance to a discourse is
determined by the addressee who hears it in context and is the sole judge of its relevance.

The speaker may try ever so hard to "say" one thing, but if the addressee "hears" another, that's just the way it is. And humans are **always** looking for contextual cues for interpreting relevance.

The underlying truth that motivates [Relevance Theory](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=relevance%20theory) is that you can't get away from relevance;  everything else conversational depends on it, and it's not under the speaker's control.

Comment: However, pp. 46 he states "Under the category of Relation I place a single maxim, namely, 'Be relevant', which is under the control of the speaker. Contrast the restatements on p. 47 which are addressee-centered vs. those on 45-6 which are speaker-centered.

Comment: Can you help me more . I'm still confused.I'm supposed to tell whether the speaker in each situation is relevant or not according to the previous utterance.

Comment: How it's impossible to violate the maxim of relevance. You can say something and the other say something comepletly different

Comment: @user6726 Does he claim the opposite elsewhere? And if so, how does he reconcile that?

Comment: @Alenanno, he first states (all of) the maxims from a speaker's perspective and then restates the underlying ideas from what look like an addressee's perspective, in terms of expectations one has of a cooperative partner. I don't see this as a contradiction, rather, it's a generalization that transcends language and the speaker / addressee distinction.